# trying to use the gstreamer-player rust crate, I get this pkg-config error

Tags: rust, gstreamer

This is the full log

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `glib-sys v0.10.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\Wu\Documents\RustProjects\mechanical\target\debug\build\glib-sys-b6b5049ea9ffd484\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GLIB_2.0_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  Failed to run `"pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "glib-2.0" "glib-2.0 >= 2.42"`: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I have this error when I try to build my project (it's empty but it's using the `gstreamer-player` crate

I was told to install pkg-config (I'm on windows) so I used MSYS2 to install it with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`

The error persisted so I added the environment variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH = H:\MSYS2\usr\lib\pkgconfig`, and I added `H:\MSYS2\usr\lib\pkgconfig` to the `path` variable

The error still persists, anyone has any idea of what I could do or what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated

Comment: Just to double check. What part of the [`Installation`->`Windows`](https://crates.io/crates/gstreamer-player#installation-windows) section did you use? `MSYS2 / pacman` or `GStreamer Binaries`?

Comment: You can remove `H:\MSYS2\usr\lib\pkgconfig` from the path, but you need to add the location of `pkg-config.exe` (possibly `H:\MSYS2\usr\bin`)